# Qt QTreeView: how to to put frames around item text?

Tags: c++, ruby, qt

I am trying to implement a TreeView where the item texts have a colored background and a frame. I do not want to put the frame around the whole item, but only around the text. Please have a look at this mock-up:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/irl8hedyxy520yy/screenshot.jpg

(a) looks like what I would like to achieve.

I understand that I have at least the following options:

- (a) Replace the items of qtreeview with qLabel widgets.

  This is possible, but I believe that creating a widget for each and every item is a bad idea. I read somewhere else that an item delegate should be used in this case, and only the visible items should be widgets. That is going to be complicated.
- (b) Use a stylesheet.

  It seems very simple and elegant, but I do not manage to frame only the text, and not the item which fills the whole column (see screenshot)
- (c) Use a qStyledItemDelegate and paint the boxes and texts as I wish.

  Certainly possible, but requires a lot of code and complexity.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this?

I am using ruby, qtbindings, and Qt4.8, but my question is about Qt in general, not about the implementation with ruby.

Thanks for any help,

Bogl

Comment: The best way to do this is using `QItemDelegate`.

Comment: QItemDelegate to paint or to add item widgets?

Comment: To paint of course. You don't need add extra widgets.

Comment: @Evgeny is right. I have done it using QItemDelegate and paintEvent will be call for all items and you can do the custom drawing. You can also control the size of items by sizeHint method.

Comment: delegate + custom drawing +1, I did similar things in Qt 4.8 and really didn't know an easier way of doing it.